# PHP - Scandir não funciona

Tags: php

Estou com problemas com `scandir` não consigo localizar o diretório de jeito nenhum, toda vez eu recebo o seguinte **Warning**

> O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado.

Vejam meu código. Utilizo o Wamp X64, Windows 10 e o PHP 5.6:

```
<?php

  $pasta = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pasta');          
  $tamanho = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'tamanho');    

   /* separador */
  $separador = '/galeriaimg/';

  // aqui recebo somente o valor que preciso ou seja o nome da pasta
  $valor  = explode($separador, $pasta);

  // repassando somente o valor necessário para a variavel
  $pasta = $valor[1];

  // Formas que eu tentei obter o retorno do Scandir todas sem sucesso!
  $dir = 'http://localhost:3030/wpauditoria/images/biblioteca/$tamanho/galeriaimg/$pasta';
  $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wpauditoria/images/biblioteca/$tamanho/galeriaimg/$pasta";
  $dir = "../../../images/biblioteca/$tamanho/galeriaimg/$pasta";
  $dir = "/wpauditoria/images/biblioteca/$tamanho/galeriaimg/$pasta";

   $files = scandir($dir);

  //echo (json_encode($files));

 ?>
```

Comment: Aonde esta localizada "fisicamente" a pasta wpauditoria?

Comment: Dentro da pasta www no Wamp c:/wamp64/www/wpauditoria

Comment: E aonde esta localizado o teu script PHP?

Comment: Vc quis dizer o código ? Nessa pasta ! É o localhost ..

Comment: Sim o código PHP que você postou na pergunta, em qual pasta esta? Dentro de `wpauditoria`?

Comment: Sim dentro dessa pasta ! Mas tá subdividida tá nesse caminho  wpauditoria/painel-admin/include/galeriaimg/ o script PHP da pergunta

Comment: Tá, mas preciso saber aonde esta o arquivo php ao menos, independente das subdivisões, a não ser que vc tenha multiplos arquivos php cada um em uma pasta que façam a mesma coisa.

Comment: Está nesse caminho ... C:/wamp64/www/wpauditoria/painel-admin/include/galeriaimg/galeria.php

Comment: Já as imagens q o scandir deve buscar está nesse local c:/wamp64/wpauditoria/imagens/biblioteca/medium/galeriaimg/galeria/

Comment: E pelo navegador você acessa o php diretamente assim `http://localhost/wpauditoria/painel-admin/include/galeriaimg/ga‌​leria.php` ou você faz include em outro .php?

Comment: Só um detalhe, faltou a porta então ficaria dessa forma localhost:3030/wpauditoria/painel-admin/galeriaimg/galeria.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema.

Estou utilizando o plugin `responsivefilemanager` para selecionar os arquivos e esse plugin tem uma opção para criar imagens em tamanho pré determinado  pastas etc, essas configurações podem ser setadas no (config.php) do plugin.

Então, quando a imagem é muito pequena, ele não cria a pasta estipulada para redimensionar no diretorio "medium" (foi dentro desse diretorio que personalizei as imagens redimensionadas) e isso originava o erro por que o caminho onde ele buscava realmente não existia, afinal fiz upload de uma imagem bem pequena que não era necessário redimensionar..

outro detalhe importante é a forma de buscar com o scandir. Aqui funcionou somente quando chamei o `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` antes do local onde o script está.

Dessa Forma:

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wpauditoria/images/biblioteca/medium/galeriaimg/galeria;
```